# Kivy: Can you have a BoxLayout within an AnchorLayout?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

*Goal:* simply have two buttons side by side in the top right of the screen.

*Attempted Method:* To use AnchorLayout to place a BoxLayout in the top right of the screen.

.kv file:

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "right"
    anchor_y: "top"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 100
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100,100
```

*Result:* This places the buttons on the bottom left of the screen, not the top right as intended.

*Question:* What's wrong with this, and what is best way to place a row of buttons anchored to the top right of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because the `BoxLayout` is getting set to the same size as the `AnchorLayout`, due to the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`. You can fix that by adding `size_hint: None, None` and `size: self.minimum_size`:

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "right"
    anchor_y: "top"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 100
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100,100
```